# About the translation result of Google Cloud TRANSLATION API

Tags: google-translate

I have a question about the translation result of Google Cloud TRANSLATION API.

We applied Google Cloud TRANSLATION API to the game like this.

1. Apply API for translating game chat.
2. If the foreign language text by other users is written in the chat window, "See Translation" button is appeared below the text. After user click the button, the text is translated to user's device language.
3. We set the translation result language become user's device language.

but, We have some translation issues below.

**[If I set device language to Malay]**

- Device language: Malay
- Game language: English
- Translation target language: Indonesian
- Expected result language: Malay
- Real result language: Sometimes Malay, sometimes English. And, sometimes it is crashed(special character)

**[If I set device language to Indonesian]**

- Device language: Indonesian
- Game language: English
- Translation target language: Vietnamese
- Expected result language: Indonesian
- Real result language: English ("See Translation" button isn't appeared at all)

P.S. We don't support Malay & Indonesian in the game.

Could you answer to me if you have a solution?
Thanks.